# What tools does your company use to manage application performance of asp.net applications?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I am not talking about application profilers or debuggers but more specific to managing the applications in production environment. So essentially monitor, identify bottlenecks, deploy fixes.

Comment: why would you not use a profiler to identify bottlenecks?

Answer (score 1):

For monitoring the application is up and running we use Nagios. 
We also use good old performance monitor for monitoring database connections, memory consumption and CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

We use [IPMonitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/ipmonitor/) to verify uptime, and it has a lot of options for pinging the site for keyword validation, HTTP response validation, and response time. You can also use SNMP to figure out responsiveness of the processor and RAM, and remaining size on hard disks, among many other options. It supports multiple servers and types of servers, not just website or database.

Additionally, we test basic uptime and response speed with AlertSite.

A 3rd party, Keynote, tests our sites to verify that they are navigable like a human would browse. They have scripts to mimic clicks and interactions.

We use Spotlight for SQL server management, and also good old perfmon for the granular problem fixing.

Answer (score 0):

We recently purchased [WildMetrix](http://www.ascendview.com/wildmetrix/default.asp) to monitor and troubleshoot performance issues for our ASP.NET applications.  It's nice because you can easily aggregate IIS, ASP.NET, and SQL Server information into a single graph or dashboard that allows you to pinpoint possible trouble spots.  We currently use it for as our primary performance reporting and track tool, along with ELMAH for Exception Tracking.